# Nginx 1.11 - nginx.conf file changed

Tags: php, linux, apache, nginx, php-7

The nginx.conf is very different in nginx version 1.11 compared to 1.6. Ownership is done by nginx instead of www-data, there is no include path for the sites-enabled directory and the new nginx.con file is around 20 lines of code.

With nginx 1.11, do I need to set an include of the web path or is this designed to pull a different nginx.conf from each website directory? Do I need to replace this nginx.conf with the sample config on the nginx website?

Answer (score 3):

It should have an `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` or something similar, so you should put your config in that directory. ie `/etc/nginx/conf.d/www.example.com.conf`

Comment: Thank you, this package maintainer does thing differently. Your guidance helped very much. Thank you, sincerely.